# Woocommerce Product Title Duplicates

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api, woocommerce-theming

I am using Astra theme and the page builder is Elementor. I am trying to remove the duplicate product tilte (woocommerce-loop-product__title) which messes the seo right now. I tried different ways but failed. Using CSS I can hide the title but I want to remove it completely so it won't show on SEO, I am using the SEO minion extension where it show me the repeated product titles in H2. The below code I am using to remove the duplicate but no success.

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_loop_product_title', 10, 2 );
```

Here is the site link: https://sjcomputers.us/refurbished-laptops/
Your help would be appreciated.
Thanks